# how can I make a bootstrap styled button text look less smudged?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I'm sure this could be improved, if you look as the js fiddle it looks blurred and a bit rubbish.  any hints on getting the text sharp and more pro please?

I'm thinking @font face to import fonts but with laravel-mix I could add somewhere?

https://jsfiddle.net/t9b8ukoz/

```
.btn-enquiry {
background-color: #C30030;    
height: 50px;
color: #ffffff;
font-family: Helvetica Neue LT Std;
border-width: 0;
font-size:20px;
border-radius: 40px;
margin-top:30px;
}

.btn-enquiry-no {
background-color: #ffffff;
border-color: #C30030;   
height: 50px;
color: #c30030;
font-family: Helvetica Neue LT Std;
border-width: 2px;
font-size:20px;
border-radius: 40px;
margin-top:30px;
}

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<button class="button btn-block btn-enquiry">Yes</button>
<button class="button btn-block btn-enquiry-no">No</button>
</div>
</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Fonts were not imported or maybe thier link is broken

Answer (score 1):

You can use url to import fonts like:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Calibri';
   font-style: italic;
   font-weight: 400;
   src: local('Calibri Italic'), local('Calibri-Italic'), 
   url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/l/font?kit=J7adnpV- 
   BGlaFfdAhLQo6btPMDoTpA&skey=36a3d5758e0e2f58&v=v9) format('woff2');
   unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, 
   U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, 
   U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

added the downloaded some different fonts to /assets/fonts folder in /resources

add this to webpack.mix.js

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.config.fileLoaderDirs.fonts = 'assets/fonts';
```

Then add this to my custom css file

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'OpenSansRegular';
src: url('../assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot');
src: url('../assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('../assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
url('../assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('../assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.svg#OpenSansRegular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
font-display: swap;}
```

When it compiles with npm and laravel mix works perfectly!